# Focus Protractor/Webdriver browser test window

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to focus Protractor/Webdriver browser test window when testing starts. By focus I mean that the test window should come on top of the other windows displayed on screen, right now it appears under the other windows.

Using Selenium chromedriver and starting Protractor from WebStorm.

I tried the following at the beginning of the scenario spec but it didn't have any effect:

```
browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
browser.driver.switchTo().window(browser.driver.getWindowHandle());
browser.switchTo().window(browser.getWindowHandle());
browser.driver.executeScript('window.focus();')
```

Comment: tried clicking on any place in the window? click always put the clicked window on top.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you eventually resolve this?

Comment: @giosakti: No, haven't found a solution yet. Will add an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something Webdriver can do since it only controls your testing window, not your operating system's window manager. However, there is a Chrome flag that might do the trick:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--start-maximized']
    }
}
```

This belongs in your `protractor.conf.js` file.

As soon as the Chrome window opens, it will maximize. On my system this puts it in front. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the onPrepare in conf.js to take a screenshot once the browser is launched. This brings the window in focus.

```
onPrepare: function() {
   return browser.takeScreenshot();
},
```